# Jquery, sliding down hidden div jumps to the top

Tags: jquery

I have a link that once I click a hidden div slides down or up, but it always jumps to the top of the page so I have to go all the way  down...

I read I had to store a height but my content is dynamic so I can't do that...

Css

```
.resultado{

    text-align: left;
}
```

Div itself

```
<div class="resultado">
<a class="mostrar" href="#">mostrar</a>
<div class="datos"><p>Hi</p></div>
</div>
```

Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".datos").hide();

        $('.resultado').delegate('.mostrar','click',function(event){

          $(this).parent().find(".datos").slideToggle();

        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
$('.resultado').delegate('.mostrar','click',function(event){
    $(this).parent().find(".datos").slideToggle();
});
```

to

```
$('.resultado').delegate('.mostrar','click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().find(".datos").slideToggle();
});
```

The default behavior of your link is to follow the named anchor and bring the top of the page into focus. By using [`event.preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) you suppress that behavior.